# Maintain session across different projects in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I have a silverlight project. There are 2 projects in the same solution. One is the Silverlight, other is the WCF. In WCF project, there is a class in which we are assigning all the session variables at the time of login. Now, I added a existing aspx project(contains only login.aspx and home.aspx) to the same solution and added the service reference. Now aspx project is the startup project. Now user will login from login.aspx page instead of login.xaml page. At the time of login, I am setting all the session variables in the class. From login page I redirect the user to Home page. In the home page user can navigate to different silverlight pages. But when I navigate between silverlight pages, I am getting all the session variables as null/0. How can I solve this? Please help me.

Here is my Service web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="DataSource=Connection\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=OfficeConnect;UserID=sa;Password=sa" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
  <hostingEnvironment idleTimeout="10000"/>
  <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
<httpHandlers>
<add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
</httpHandlers>
 </system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="PictureBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:30:30" receiveTimeout="00:30:30" closeTimeout="00:30:30" openTimeout="00:30:30" >
      <readerQuotas
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxDepth="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSPictureBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:30:30" receiveTimeout="00:30:30" closeTimeout="00:30:30" openTimeout="00:30:30" >
      <readerQuotas
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxDepth="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="OfficeConnect.Web.ImageServiceBehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>                
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="OfficeConnect.Web.ImageServiceBehaviour" name="OfficeConnect.Web.wcfOfficeConnect">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSPictureBinding" contract="OfficeConnect.Web.IwcfOfficeConnect">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>       
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>  
 <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
 <handlers>
   <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  </handlers>
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
 <security>
   <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"></requestLimits>                                                
   </requestFiltering>
 </security>
 </system.webServer>  
  <system.diagnostics>
   <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
         <listeners>
           <add name="traceListener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData="E:\Harsha\Traces.svclog"  />
        </listeners>
     </source>
    </sources>
 </system.diagnostics>
 </configuration>
```

This was the web.config file generated when I added the service reference to the ASP project

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <authentication mode="Forms"  >
    <forms defaultUrl="Application_Masters/LoginPage.aspx"
           slidingExpiration="true"
           name=".ASPXAUTH"  timeout="20" cookieless="AutoDetect"
         >
    </forms>
  </authentication>
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MashPortalService.MyServiceBehaviour">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"  />
        <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="05:05:00" />
        <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <!--<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>-->
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <!--<StructureMapServiceBehavior />-->
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="LogoResizer.WCF.ServiceTypes.ImageResizerService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:900/mex/"/>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9000/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ImageResizerServiceContract" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="LogoResizer.WCF.ServiceContracts.IImageResizerService" />
      <endpoint  address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" />
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="LAN_Endpoint1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IwcfOfficeConnect" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="LAN_Endpoint1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </binding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IwcfOfficeConnect" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:3312/wcfOfficeConnect.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IwcfOfficeConnect"
            contract="ServiceReference.IwcfOfficeConnect" name="LAN_Endpoint1">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:3312/wcfOfficeConnect.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IwcfOfficeConnect"
            contract="ServiceReference.IwcfOfficeConnect" name="WSHttpBinding_IwcfOfficeConnect">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is the Silverlight client config that was generated when I added service reference to the Silverlight project.

```
  <configuration>
     <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LAN_Endpoint1" closeTimeout="00:30:30" openTimeout="00:30:30"
      receiveTimeout="00:30:30" sendTimeout="00:30:30" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:3312/wcfOfficeConnect.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LAN_Endpoint1"
    contract="ServiceReference.IwcfOfficeConnect" name="LAN_Endpoint1" />
</client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

This is the class in the WCF project in which we maintain session. When we login we assign session to all the variables and fetch the same when required.

```
public class ClsSessionMaintenance
{
    public void assign_compdb(int mainlogin)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["mainloginid"] = mainlogin;            
    }

   public static int getmaindbuserid()
    {
        int loginId = Convert.ToInt32((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["mainloginid"]);
        return loginId;
    }

}
```

Is there any wrong with the configuration files? Through a method in the WCF service I am able to successfully assign the session in the ClsSessionMaintenance class. It's fine till here. After successful login, I am redirecting the user to HomePage.aspx which has the master page HomeMaster. In HomeMaster page, there are hyperlinks so that user can navigate to different Silverlight xaml pages. But after assigning the session, I am immediately calling the function which fetches the session from the ClsSessionMaintenance class. But I get the session value as O. Why is it happening? Please help me.

Comment: Did you enable the `ASP.NET` compatibility in the `WCF` service? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx

Comment: @RicardoPontual Yes. I did. Under <System.ServiceModel> <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>